# how to format a string or number to thousand group in typescript

Tags: typescript

My function just want to format a number or string from 'xxxxx.xx' to 'xx,xxx.xx' or xxxxx.xx to 'xx,xxx.xx'

```
function format(text: number | string): string {
  return `${+text.toLocaleString()}`;
}
console.log(format(123456)); #123,456
console.log(format(123456.78)); #123,456.78
console.log(format('123456')); #123,456
console.log(format('123456.78')); #123,456.78
=> 
NaN
NaN
123456
123456.78
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: yes, what i am wondering why my function return NaN?

Comment: The code is running `+` on `text.toLocaleString()`, which returns `NaN`. If you do `(+text).toLocaleString()` then it works.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function format(text: number | string): string {
  return Number(text).toLocaleString();
}
```

`Number` converts a string to a number, see [Number at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).